# Ender 3 Pro with BLtouch + BigTreeTech Auto level not compensating

Tags: creality-ender-3, bltouch, skr-mini-e3, bigtreetech

As the title says, I have an Ender 3 Pro + BLtouch v3.1 and BigTreeTech SKR mini E3 v2.0. I have the SKR loaded with "firmware-bltouch-for-z-homing.bin" but my printer does not seem to be auto leveling. I'm fairly new to 3D printing and I have no idea what I am missing. My bed seems pretty warped but that isn't an issue for small print. For larger prints I think I think I need to enable mesh bed leveling but I'm not sure how.

I have my start G-code setup as:

```
; Ender 3 Custom Start G-code
M140 S{material_bed_temperature_layer_0} ; Set Heat Bed temperature
M190 S{material_bed_temperature_layer_0} ; Wait for Heat Bed temperature
M104 S160; start warming extruder to 160
G28 ; Home all axes
G29 ; Auto bed-level (BL-Touch)
M420 S1; enable auto bed-level?
G92 E0 ; Reset Extruder
M104 S{material_print_temperature_layer_0} ; Set Extruder temperature
G1 X0.1 Y20 Z0.3 F5000.0 ; Move to start position
M109 S{material_print_temperature_layer_0} ; Wait for Extruder temperature
; G1 Z2.0 F3000 ; Move Z Axis up little to prevent scratching of Heat Bed
G1 X0.1 Y200.0 Z0.3 F1500.0 E15 ; Draw the first line
G1 X0.4 Y200.0 Z0.3 F5000.0 ; Move to side a little
G1 X0.4 Y20 Z0.3 F1500.0 E30 ; Draw the second line
G92 E0 ; Reset Extruder
G1 Z2.0 F3000 ; Move Z Axis up little to prevent scratching of Heat Bed
; End of custom start GCode
```

It heats up the bed, does the 5x5 auto level and then heats the extruder but when printing I do not see the Z axis moving throughout the first layer to compensate for the warped bed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Should I be using "firmware-bltouch.bin" instead and reinstall my Z switch?